# MS Excel: calculate the average datetime

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a column with this values:

```
2004-02-11 00:00:00.000 +00:00
2016-04-13 18:19:47.000 +00:00
2016-04-13 18:20:51.000 +00:00
2016-04-14 08:44:21.000 +00:00
2016-04-14 08:47:40.000 +00:00
2016-04-14 08:53:21.000 +00:00
2016-04-14 09:03:22.000 +00:00
2016-04-14 09:15:22.000 +00:00
2016-04-14 09:29:07.000 +00:00
2016-04-14 09:56:36.000 +00:00
```

And I like to do the Average of this dateTime. I tried with the avg function but it was unsuccessful.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are your values in date or text format? What happens if you change the format of these values to "General"?

Comment: @Taosique it's in date formate. Now I tried to change to General and it happens the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datetime values include UTC timezone offset (the `+00:00`) part. Excel does not support this feature in datetime values, so your values are not recognized as valid datetime and thus parsed as text.

You need to extract the part of datetime text in valid format and then convert this text to datetime values before you can `AVG()` them.

Make a helper column with this formula for your values (if your values in column `A:A`):

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT($A1,19))
```

and drag this formula down. It will display values like `42474` - that's a date value, you can format is as a date by changing cell format. Now you can calculate `AVG()` on these values.